# How to move a file to a subdirectory ? C#

Tags: c#, .net

I wanna do a C# application that does this:

1. Selects a folder
2. Copies all the files from that folder into that folder +/results/

Very simple, but can't get it work.

Here is my code:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Path.GetFullPath(file));
            //string path=Path.Combine(Path.GetFullPath(file), "results");
            //MessageBox.Show(path);
            string path2 = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
            path2 = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(file), @"results\");
            path2 = Path.Combine(path2, file);
            MessageBox.Show(path2);
        }
```

Comment: You're not doing anything here but looping through an array of the FileNames, then creating a string variable with the new location.

Comment: yep, I know but I wanna move the file, with File.Move after I get the correct paths. I have the first correct path "c:/dir/bla/file.txt" but I can't get the second path which would be "c:/dir/bla/results/file.txt"

Comment: Do you want to move or copy the files in the destination directory? In title you say 'move' in question body you say 'copy'

Answer (score 6):

First, create the destination directory, if not exists

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);  
string destPath = Path.Combine(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "results");
if(Directory.Exists(destPath) == false)
    Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath);
```

then inside your loop

```
    foreach (string file in files)  
    {  
        string path2 = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(file));  
        File.Move(file, path2);
    }
```

Please note that [File.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move) cannot be used to overwrite an existing file.
You will get an IOException if the file exist in the destination directory.

If you only want to copy, instead of Move, simply change the `File.Move` statement with `File.Copy(file, path2, true);`. This overload will overwrite your files in the destination directory without questions.

Comment: You don't have to check if destPath exists. CreateDirectory will do nothing if the path already exists, so just call it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to move the files (and not copy them) to the new sub-folder then...

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
foreach (FileInfo f in d.GetFiles())
{
    string fold = Path.Combine(f.DirectoryName, @"results\");

    if (!Directory.Exists(fold))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(fold);

    File.Move(f.FullName, Path.Combine(fold, f.Name));
}
```

This is just an example to answer the question directly but you should also handle exceptions, etc. For instance, this example assumes the user will have permission to create the directory. Furthermore, it assumes file(s) do not already exist in the destination directory with the same name(s). How you handle such scenarios depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to relocate the entire directory, you can use `Directory.Move` to achieve this.

```
string path1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
string path2 = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(file), @"results\");
Directory.Move(path1, path2);
```

Or if you just want to copy the folder (without deleting the first directory), you'll need to do it manually.

```
string path1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
string path2 = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(file), @"results\");

foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(path1))
{
    File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(path2, file));
    // File.Move(file, Path.Combine(path2, file)); // use this to move instead of copy
}
```

*I haven't tested this, so some modifications might be necessary*